# Reference request for dual spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, dual-spaces

I am a graduate student of Mathematics.I want to study dual spaces,linear functionals and transpose of a linear operator.But I am lacking a suitable text for that.I have tried Hoffmann Kunze and Friedberg-Insel-Spence but those books lack motivation.I am finding a book that gives motivation for studying dual spaces and also explains the theory nicely.Can someone help me find a suitable text?

Comment: If you are looking for a reference request, why not *tag it* with [reference-request]?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The reference request tag is there already.

Comment: Why not ask your advisor?

Comment: @JohnDouma Advisor suggested Hoffmann Kunze but I am not comfortable with it.

Comment: The reference request tag is there "already" because I put it there after I noted that you you *should have* put it there. It didn't just show up automatically.

Comment: Then you should tell your advisor you are not comfortable with it and see if he has another suggestion. Your advisor is always the first and second person to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities I can think of that you may wish to look at, and see if they suit your taste/learning style. One is *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Axler, which goes into all the topics you mention, although from memory doesn't go too deep into motivation. I do recall that the topic of dual spaces and functionals is dealt with pretty well. There are also lots of end-of-chapter problems, and solutions are pretty easily found online.
If you are affiliated with a university you can download it for free on the SpringerLink website: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-11080-6 (the material on dual spaces begins around p.101.)

Another one is *Linear Algebra and Geometry* by Kostrikin/Manin, which uses a geometric context to motivate most of the material covered, which is mostly upper-level linear algebra. They cover the topics you mentioned, but its been a while since I looked at it, so I can't recall the quality of the treatment of those topics specifically. However, the book is of very high quality, and I do remember getting a lot out of it. Anyway, take a look!